# Wha's the best EVs for a Charmander?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a perfect IVs Charmander, Jolly nature. What's the best EVs to train him?
HP, Attack, Defense, Special Atack, Special Defense and speed.

Comment: This really depends on the moves you plan to use with it.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has a series of answers, all dependent on exactly what you expect out of your Charmander and where you're taking him.

If you're sticking to the storyline, then EVs don't really matter. The Elite Four are easily beaten through matching type weaknesses and leveling. EVs don't really play a huge factor unless you're severely underleveled.

If you're talking about wifi competitions and battles with other people, then it depends on what you want. Are you battling in Little Cup (unevolved, no higher than L5)? Or are you playing with standard rules?

As for standard rules, there are currently two or three popular builds for competitive Charizard: Mega X and Mega Y. Mega Charizard X focuses on physical damage so you'll want to go for the typical 252/252/4 spread (Attack/Speed/HP, respectively). Mega Charizard Y, on the other hand, goes for all-out special damage so you'll go with 252/252/4 again (Special Attack/Speed/HP this time).

There are some other alternative movesets for Charizard (Bulky Charizard X with a 252/136/120 split on Speed/HP/Attack) as well for you to consider.

Now you mentioned that your Charmander is of a Jolly Nature. This helps us narrow things down as Jolly is a +Speed, -Special Attack Nature, which means you probably shouldn't be using this Charmander as a special sweeper (so the Mega Charizard Y build is probably out the window). In this case, I'd probably consider going with one of the physical-oriented builds if you want to play competitively.